# Convert unix timestamp to hh:mm:ss:SSS (where SSS is milliseconds) in AWK

Tags: linux, time, awk, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How can I convert unix timestamp to hh:mm:ss:SSS (where SSS is milliseconds) in AWK.

For example:

```
echo 1456478048306 > time
cat time | awk ....... > readable_time_format
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bash for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
ts="1456478048306"
unix_epoch=${ts:0:-3}
ms=${ts:((-3)):3}

echo "$(date -d@"${unix_epoch}" +%H:%M:%S):${ms}"
```

---

Btw, of course you can also use `awk`. However awk does not allow to simplify things here a lot, the algorithm is more or less the same:

```
awk -v ts="1456478048306" '{
    unix_epoch=substr(ts, 0, length(ts)-3)
    ms=substr(ts, length(ts)-2, 3)
    print strftime("%H:%M:%S", unix_epoch) ":" ms
}'
```