# awk convert quoted timestamp to specific date time format

Tags: bash, awk

I need to convert unix timestamp value (in the first field of lof file) to specific date time format (%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%3N)

To give you an example. I have a log file looking like this

```
"1456316486","1000","11678","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","1","0.00","0.00","1792364","652108","8.02","0.00","0.00","0.00","0","remmina"
```

and I need it to look like this

```
"02/24/2016 13:21:26.000","1000","11678","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","1","0.00","0.00","1792364","652108","8.02","0.00","0.00","0.00","0","remmina"
```

to be able to import it into another tool.

P.S. I am aware of the fact there is a bunch of examples how to do this, but as an awk n00b I was not able to get it to do exactly what I want.

thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert unix timestamp to hh:mm:ss:SSS (where SSS is milliseconds) in AWK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648508/convert-unix-timestamp-to-hhmmsssss-where-sss-is-milliseconds-in-awk)

Answer (score 2):

I tried mpez0 elegant solution with the `$1+0`, but for me it didn't work. I had to explicitly remove the `"` from `$1` before the strftime, and so I came up with this solution for GNU-Awk 4.0.1:

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{gsub(/"/,"",$1 ); $1 = strftime("\"%D %T.000\"",$1); print; }' file
```

- `%D` means `%m/%d/%y` and `%T` means `%H:%M:%S`
- I could not find a format for the milliseconds, so I put a fixed `.000` in
- setting the input field separator and the output field separator with the `-v` to get input and output separated with `,`

Comment: just a minor adjustment so it outputs the first field quoted `awk -F, '{gsub(/"/,"",$1 ); $1 = "\""strftime("%D %T.000",$1)"\""; print; }' file`

Comment: @MartinPavlik I added `\"` inside the strfttime string.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for strftime:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {$2=strftime("%D %T.000")} 1' file
"02/26/16 07:53:29.000","1000","11678","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","1","0.00","0.00","1792364","652108","8.02","0.00","0.00","0.00","0","remmina"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of awk with timestamp extensions over the original (which you likely are), then

timestr = strftime("%m/%d/%Y %T.000", $1+0)

should give the string you want. You need the +0 to convert from the string of digits to a number.

Comment: Adding 0 to an input string that doesn't start with a digit (e.g. a `"` in this case) will just make the resulting number 0. Number conversion strips off trailing non-digits but not leading ones.